# Как сделать так, пушку, смотрящую на курсор? unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я занимаюсь разработкой 2d игры на unity, с видом сверху. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы пушка смотрела на курсор,  когда он на экране. Заметьте, то что мне нужно, и поворот пушки, в зависимости от движения курсора - разные вещи.

Comment: подсказка: координаты мыши, координаты пушки, треугольник, угол, ориентация изображения по просчитанному углу.

Comment: Есть классная функция atan2(y, x) - она может помочь. Почитайте про нее.

Comment: `Заметьте, то что мне нужно` а вы сами что-то пытались сделать? Или вам нужно, чтобы мы за вас игру сделали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам поможет этот код:

```
var dir = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, Mathf.Atan2 (dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
```

1. Получаем координаты мышки
2. Переводим в координаты мира
3. Находим вектор направления от объекта до мышки
4. Через `Atan2` получаем угол в радианах
5. Переводим в градусы
6. Меняем угол поворота объекта через свойство `eulerAngles`